# Read Excel worksheet located in a SharePoint folder using Python

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I am hoping to get help with a simple code in Python programming language to read an Excel worksheet located in SharePoint?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Comment: You can use Microsoft Graph API to read excel from sharepoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http , Please take a look [Retrieve items from sahrepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you can call the api in python